# Internet Explorer Animation Fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using on hover animation on this page: http://bit.ly/xtvgSq

You can see it working correctly on Chrome and Firefox, using CSS3 transitions.

On IE I'm using this code to use Jquery opacity fading to replicate the effect. However when I hover onto the title in each panel, the fading disappears. I want it to keep the fade even when I hover onto the project's title, in the same fashion as it works in Chrome and Firefox. How can I do that?

Here's the jQuery code I'm using:

```
if( jQuery('body').hasClass('ie8') || jQuery('body').hasClass('ie7') || jQuery('body').hasClass('ie9')) {
var projectImages = jQuery('.project-panel-overlay').siblings('img');

projectImages.hover(
function() {
    jQuery(this).animate({
    opacity: .4
    }, 300);
},
function() {
    jQuery(this).animate({
    opacity: 1
    }, 300);
}
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this (example: http://jsfiddle.net/FNNtT/5/):

```
jQuery('.hitbox').live('mouseenter',function(){
    jQuery(this).children('img').animate({
    opacity: .4
    }, 300);
});

jQuery('.hitbox').live('mouseleave',function(){
    jQuery(this).children('img').animate({
    opacity: 1
    }, 300);
});
```

You need to modify your html slightly as well:

```
<div class="project-panel">
                    <a class="hitbox" href=http://jpgalea.com/eco/projects/kangaroo-ground/>
                    <div class="project-panel-overlay">
                        <div class="project-panel-intro">
                            <p class="name">Kangaroo Ground</p>
                            <p class="year">2011/2012</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <img width="235" height="446" src="http://jpgalea.com/eco/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/featured41.jpg" class="attachment-featured-image-project wp-post-image" alt="" title="" />                    </a>
                </div>
```

Notice the anchor has a class called "hitbox".

This will now target the entire section rather than the img. In the code that was posted originally the selector only targeted the image, which is a sub element under the anchor that does NOT include the text.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what I need to insert? I can only understand jQuery with the knowledge I have, but don't really how to know to add such a handler, thanks.

Comment: There is an error in JS fiddle, it isn't my code, I don't know where it is coming from. It is complaining about window height, just ignore it.